# Missing box-shadow at the bottom of an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, box-shadow

I have this slide show: http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Nepal/ running in an iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Nepal/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="240" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

in a table, displayed on this page: http://www.andrewolff.nl/TestAlbum/EmbeddedAlbums/

The slide show consist of absolute positioned images with a border radius and shadow:

```
#slideimage {
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

This works fine except the shadow is not working at the bottom.
I tried already with a margin of 10px around the image, but that does not help. A padding of 10px does also not help.
I played also with the `z-index` without result.
Who know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

just give height and make it important. It will start working

```
#slideimage
{
   height:200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Well that solves the problem, but it introduces another problem: not all images do have the same height, so some pictures are distorted.

Comment: In that case you will likely want to make the images fit ahead of time. That is an inherent problem with sliders.

Answer (score 0):

Well Gurmatpal guided me to the solution: I did generate the albums again with [program jAlbum and my Slide Show 4 skin](http://jalbum.net/en/skins/skin/Slide%20Show%204) but limited the maximum height to 230px.
It could also be solved with css:

```
#slideimage {
  border-radius: 7px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  max-height:230px !important; 
}
```